# advanced related videos search mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a youtube style website, and below a video you are watching, i have to put the related videos, and i can't do the mysql query, so i thought you could help me.
The search must return the similar videos basing on tags and categories (sorry if i write something wrong, english is not my native language), so the video that has more matches in both tags and categories is at the top.
My tables are

"VIDEOS"
video_id(int)
user_id(int)
title(varchar)

"VIDEO_CATS"
cat_id(int)
category(varchar)
video_id(int)

"VIDEO_TAGS"
tag_id(int)
tag(varchar)
video_id(int)

the results I need would have to be like this or similar(example with 3 rows returned):
(RELATED VIDEOS TO VIDEO_ID=1234)

```
VIDEO_ID     TITLE           MATCHES
345          myvideo         12
584          examplename1    4
432          othername       2
124          name4           0
```

Oh! and if it is possible, i need that if there are no matches, the query still returns me values just like the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question, this should work returning all videos, ordering by those with the most matches in the cats and tags table:

```
SELECT V.Video_Id, 
    V.Title, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Cat_Id) + COUNT(DISTINCT Tag_Id) Matches
FROM Videos V
  LEFT JOIN Video_Cats VC ON VC.Video_Id = V.Video_Id
    AND VC.Cat_ID IN (SELECT Cat_Id FROM Video_Cats WHERE Video_Id = 1234)
  LEFT JOIN Video_Tags VT ON VT.Video_Id = V.Video_Id
    AND VT.Tag_ID IN (SELECT Tag_Id FROM Video_Tags WHERE Video_Id = 1234)
WHERE V.Video_Id <> 1234
GROUP BY V.Video_Id
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3699/1)

Or this might yield a better performance not using `IN`, but combining with `JOINs`:

```
SELECT V.Video_Id, 
  V.Title, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT VC2.Cat_Id) + COUNT(DISTINCT VT2.Tag_Id) Matches
FROM Videos V
  LEFT JOIN Video_Cats VC1 ON VC1.Video_Id = 1234
  LEFT JOIN Video_Cats VC2 ON VC2.Video_Id = V.Video_Id AND VC1.Cat_Id = VC2.Cat_Id
  LEFT JOIN Video_Tags VT1 ON VT1.Video_Id = 1234
  LEFT JOIN Video_Tags VT2 ON VT2.Video_Id = V.Video_Id AND VT1.Tag_Id = VT2.Tag_Id
WHERE V.Video_Id <> 1234
GROUP BY V.Video_Id
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: @user1342980 -- np, glad I could help!